# Foreach with 3-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I was studying multidimensional arrays in PHP and wanted to try some myself, I manage to loop through a 2-dimensional one easily but I get a bit stuck with a 3-dimensional one.

here's my original code

```
        $inscrits = [

            [
                'Nom' =>'Leonos',
                'Age' => '24',
                'Mail' =>'leonos@gmail.com'
            ],
            [
                'Nom' =>'Leodos',
                'Age' => '25',
                'Mail' =>'leodos@gmail.com'
            ],
            [
                'Nom' =>'Leotros',
                'Age' => '26',
                'Mail' =>'leotros@gmail.com'
            ],
        ];
```

original loop

```
foreach ($inscrits as $ligne => $infos) {
           echo '<table><tr><td>Membre n°</td><td>Nom</td><td>Age</td><td>Mail</td>></tr>
           <tr><td>' .($ligne+1). '</td>';
            foreach($infos as $info) {
                echo '<td>'.$info.'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr></table><br><br>';
        }
```

Which does exactly what I want, but I have now added another array in the already created ones and I'd like to add it to the table, but I have no idea how, everything I tried failed miserably

new array

```
$inscrits = [

            [
                'Nom' =>'Leonos',
                'Age' => '24',
                'Mail' =>'leonos@gmail.com',
                'Notes' => [
                    'Anglais' => '20',
                    'PHP' => '15',
                ],
            ],
            [
                'Nom' =>'Leodos',
                'Age' => '25',
                'Mail' =>'leodos@gmail.com',
                'Notes' => [
                    'Anglais' => '20',
                    'PHP' => '15',
                ],
            ],
            [
                'Nom' =>'Leotros',
                'Age' => '26',
                'Mail' =>'leotros@gmail.com',
                'Notes' => [
                    'Anglais' => '20',
                    'PHP' => '15',
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

it displays "array" in the corresponding column but I'm not sure how to go on about reading the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **array_walk_recursive**

for example:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $key) {  
    echo "<td>$key => $value </td>";
});
```

or

```
foreach ($inscrits as $ligne => $infos) {
           echo '<table><tr><td>Membre n°</td><td>Nom</td><td>Age</td><td>Mail</td>></tr>
           <tr><td>' .($ligne+1). '</td>';
            foreach($infos as $info) {
                if(is_array(info)) {
                    echo '<td>';
                    foreach($info as $note)
                        echo $note.' ';
                    echo '</td>';
                }   
                else
                    echo '<td>'.$info.'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr></table><br><br>';
        }
```

Comment: thank you! it's the is_array() check that I was completely missing. Thanks a bunch